# Array of samples from multivariate gaussian distribution Python

Tags: machine-learning, probability, python, numpy

I am trying to build in Python the scatter plot in part 2 of Elements of Statistical Learning. First it is said to generate

> 10 means mk
>   from a bivariate Gaussian distribution N((1,0)T,I) and labeled this class
>   BLUE. Similarly, 10 more were drawn from N((0,1)T,I) and labeled class
>   ORANGE.

I draw one such mean from bivariate gaussian using

`from numpy.random import multivariate_normal as mvnorm
cov = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
mean_or = [1,0]
mean_bl = [0,1]
m_or = [0]*10
m_bl = [0]*10
for i in range(10):

    m_or[i] = list(mvnorm(mean_or,cov))
    m_bl[i] = list(mvnorm(mean_bl,cov))`

Is there a more elegant way to generate a vector of 10 means in python, a one-liner replacing the for-loop here ?

Side question : what difference between drawing samples from $N((1,0)T,I)$ and $N((0,1)T,I)$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are drawing samples from that distribution rather than estimates of the mean. I'm not sure if this is what you want to be doing. If you just want to draw samples a simple way would be

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import numpy as np

n_samps_to_draw = 10

mvn(mean=[0,1],cov=np.eye(2)).rvs(n_samps_to_draw)
```

alternatively, you could just go

```
n_samps_to_draw = 10
m_or = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,1],np.eye(2),n_samps_to_draw)
m_bl = np.random.multivariate_normal([1,0],np.eye(2),n_samps_to_draw)
```

if you wanted to sample 10 measurements of the mean, you could just run

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import numpy as np
n_samples_to_est_mean = 500
n_mean_ests = 10

[np.mean(mvn(mean=[0,1],cov=np.eye(2)).rvs(n_samples_to_est_mean),axis=0) for _ in range(n_mean_ests)]
```

or again with just numpy

```
import numpy as np
n_samples_to_est_mean = 500
n_mean_ests = 10
[np.mean(np.random.multivariate_normal([0,1],np.eye(2), n_samples_to_est_mean),axis=0) for _ in range(n_mean_ests)]
```

Comment: the books says drawing 10 means from the bivariate distribution, isn't it what I am doing ? ( drawing 10 points from bivariate distribution )

Comment: without having the book and knowing the context, I'm not sure. It could be that you are trying to estimate the mean 10 times or draw 10 samples. Code for both is above.

Comment: ((1,0),)  is a multivariate normal distribution where the mean of the first dimension is 1 and the mean of the second dimension is 0. ((0,1),)  is the other way around. mean of the first dimension is 0, mean of the second dimension is 1.